# OAuth issues with Codeigniter/i18n URLs

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth, linkedin-api

I've been successfully accessing the LinkedIn API through my CodeIngiter application. I moved to a nearly identical server and implemented i18n library and it's stopped working.

After the user authenticates on LinkedIn it returns to the correct URL, but generates a series of errors beginning with `Undefined index: oauth_verifier`

After using an [i18n library](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/CodeIgniter_2.1_internationalization_i18n) my URLs now have two letter language codes in the 1st segment like 'en' or 'br'.

EDIT: This is the [Linkedin library](http://thinkdiff.net/php/integrate-linkedin-api-part-2/) I'm using.

I believe this is causing routing issues with the setting of $_REQUEST['oath_verifier']

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Excerpt from controller:

```
class LinkLogin extends MY_Controller {

function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('profile_model');
    $this->load->model('generic_model');
    include_once (APPPATH.'libraries/Linkedin.php');         
}

function index(){
}

function initiate(){

    session_start();
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $config['linkedin_access'] = "***";
    $config['linkedin_secret'] = "***";
    $config['base_url']  = "http://www.youinapage.com/linklogin/initiate/";

    if ($this->uri->segment(4) == 'profile') {
    $config['callback_url']  = "http://www.youinapage.com/linklogin/get_profile_linkedin/";
    }
    if ($this->uri->segment(4) == 'resume') {
    $config['callback_url']  = "http://www.youinapage.com/linklogin/get_resume_linkedin/";
    }

function get_resume_linkedin() {

    session_start();
    $this->load->library('format');

    $config['linkedin_access'] = "***";
    $config['linkedin_secret'] = "***";
    $config['base_url']  = "http://www.youinapage.com/linklogin/initiate/";
    $config['callback_url']  = "http://www.youinapage.com/linklogin/get_resume_linkedin/";

        # First step is to initialize with your consumer key and secret. We'll use an out-of-band oauth_callback
$linkedin = new LinkedIn($config['linkedin_access'], $config['linkedin_secret'], $config['callback_url'] );
//$linkedin->debug = true;


            # First step is to initialize with your consumer key and secret. We'll use an out-of-band oauth_callback
    $linkedin = new LinkedIn($config['linkedin_access'], $config['linkedin_secret'], $config['callback_url'] );
    //$linkedin->debug = true;

   if (isset($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'])){
        $_SESSION['oauth_verifier']     = $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'];

        $linkedin->request_token    =   unserialize($_SESSION['requestToken']);
        $linkedin->oauth_verifier   =   $_SESSION['oauth_verifier'];
        $linkedin->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);

        $_SESSION['oauth_access_token'] = serialize($linkedin->access_token);
        header("Location: " . $config['callback_url']);
        exit;
   }
   else{
        $linkedin->request_token    =   unserialize($_SESSION['requestToken']);
        $linkedin->oauth_verifier   =   $_SESSION['oauth_verifier']; // ERROR: Undefined index: oauth_verifier
        $linkedin->access_token     =   unserialize($_SESSION['oauth_access_token']);
   }
```

Comment: Well, from the looks of it, it is because `oath_verifier` isn't set in the session, which could happen if you do two requests after each other  without `$_REQUEST['oath_verifier']` being set.  Or by just going to the controller without requesting `oath_verifier`.  Why are you actually checking if it is in `$_REQUEST`?  I never had to do so in codeigniter.

Comment: Where is that excerpt actually from?  Within a method or within the constructor?

Comment: Got it. The excerpt is from the controller in CodeIgniter I created that handles all the interaction with the LinkedIn library that I'm using (not mine). Would it be helpful if I posted anything else? This code all worked before -- I'm nearly certain the i18n library is affecting the way URLs are interpreted causing the issue, just don't see how that affects the session though.

Comment: Is `oath_verifier` supposed to get set by post or get-requests?  I don't really see how it will be set so I can't tell how it will choose what path to take.  It would be helpfull to see how that's decided.  It would also still be usefull to know if that excerpt comes from a method of the controller, or the constructor of the controller.  Or tell us the name of the function where you took that excerpt from and what your class/controller is called.

Comment: Sure thing. I've added nearly all of my controller and a link to the library I'm using. That should show everything. Help's much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments and post, I'm guessing you are trying to use the same method twice in a row, so you get logged in.  Seems weird but whatever.

The i18n you use will however change your routes to encorporate the languages so you should update your url's which you are setting inside your to controller to also use that language or a language.

In codeigniter, you should always try to set url's by the use of `site_url()`.  This way you can easily port your application to other domainnames/locations.  In this case, the localisation-library would also have changed the url's for you.

You should change all references to urls as follows:

```
$config['base_url']      = site_url("linklogin/initiate/");
$config['callback_url']  = site_url("linklogin/get_resume_linkedin/");
```

To use `site_url()`, you will need the [URL Helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html).  You should include that helper before trying to use site_url().  But you already include it in your constructor, so no problems there.

You should also replace the use of `header(...); exit;` with `redirect();`.  If you die after sending the header, codeigniter will not fully run and your logs will not be fully completed.

```
redirect($config['callback_url']); // Replaces: header($config['callback_url']);exit;
redirect('linklogin/get_resume_linkedin/'); // Alternative to above statement
```

I would also advice you to check out the [manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/) to check out the build-in session class and the input class.

Comment: Thx for the help! I'm looking into everything you wrote...i had tried site_url earlier and the resulting URL was `http://www.youinapage.com/en/http://www.youinapage.com/linklogin/get_resume_linkedin?oauth_token=b424eca2-8063-4c8a-8180-71f826aa8aaa&oauth_verifier=56689` which is why i felt the i18n library is the culprit.

Comment: Thanks again -- everything worked out once I correctly applied all of your suggestions.